# XmlRPC: The method addHandler is undefined for the type WebServer

Tags: java, apache, xml-rpc

I am trying to implement a sample XML-RPC code from [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/xml-rpc/xml_rpc_examples.htm) using apache.xmlrpc.

```
import org.apache.xmlrpc.*;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Hashtable;
import java.util.Vector;

public class JavaServer {    
    public Integer sum(int x, int y) {
        return new Integer(x + y);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {   System.out.println("Attempting to start XML-RPC Server...");
            WebServer server = new WebServer(80);
            server.addHandler("sample", new JavaServer());
            server.start();
            System.out.println("Started successfully.");
            System.out.println("Accepting requests. (Halt program to stop.)");
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            System.err.println("JavaServer: " + exception);
        }
    }
}
```

But on this line: `server.addHandler("sample", new JavaServer());` of the above code I am getting the following error.

> The method addHandler(String, Rpc Server) is undefined for the type
>   WebServer.

I have imported a jar from the newest XML-RPC from apache `apache-xmlrpc-3.1.3-bin.zip`.

Does anybody have any idea why I get this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like the method does not exist in versions 3. 
The problem was that many examples existing on the net today about XML-RPC use older versions. Hence, I got `xmlrpc-helma-1.0.jar` from [this link](http://mavenhub.com/mvn/central/xmlrpc/xmlrpc-helma/1.0).

Apache XML-RPC writes in its [website](http://ws.apache.org/xmlrpc/xmlrpc2/)

> "If you have code using the Helma library, all you should have to do is
>   change the import statements in your code from helma.xmlrpc.* to
>   org.apache.xmlrpc.*. "

But it does not work. There is no `helma.xmlrpc.WebServer.addHandler` method in version 3.
I do not know what new method replaces in newer versions. But using the older API, the error is resolved for now.